# What does 'execute(Runnable command)' method of Executor exactly do?

Tags: java

```
private ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); 

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  executor1.execute(some runnable command);
```

Can anyone explain what is exactly happening in these above 2 statements? In which statement is a new thread created? How many new threads are created?

Comment: I think it does exactly what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) says...

Comment: *Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads are created the moment you create a new fixed thread-pool, but these threads don't do anything yet. They are standing by and are waiting for tasks to perform.

When you tell the fixed thread-pool executor to execute a `Runnable`, that runnable will be sent to one of the idle threads which will then start to run it parallel to your programs execution. When the `Runnable` terminates, the finished thread is put on standby again and waits for further work.

When you tell the executor service to execute runnables while all threads in the pool are busy, those runnables will be put into a queue and will be executed when a runnable has finished.

Answer (score 0):

The executor message will execute the runnable you specified in a different thread.

```
private ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

means you are creating an executor object with 5 threads in its thread pool. So when ever a request comes in, it will use one thread from these five and executes the request.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  executor1.execute(some runnable command);
```

This statement means you are providing executor service with 10 tasks. Since the executor has 5 threads, it will starts executing the first five task and the later tasks will be scheduled for execution. That is when a task among the first five is finished, that thread will comes back to the thread pool and then it will be allotted for executing the 6th task.

For example :

Thread 1 : executing task 1

Thread 2 : executing task 2

Thread 3 : executing task 3

Thread 4 : executing task 4

Thread 5 : executing task 5

Suppose Thread 3 finishes its work, then :

Thread 3 : executing task 6

Afterwards suppose Thread 1 finishes its work :

Thread 1 : executing task 7

and so on...

until all the scheduled taskes are finished. Since the thread pool is of size 5, only a maximum of 5 parallel tasks will be done at a time. Hope my explanation will help you.

Comment: So, when Thread 3 completes a task and goes back to the pool, in what state it would be? I mean, when Thread 3 takes another task for execution, is it restarted?

Comment: So, when Thread 3 completes a task and goes back to the pool, in what state it would be? I mean, when Thread 3 takes another task for execution, is it restarted?

Comment: Yeah, when a thread completes its task, it will be returned to the pool. If the executor is having any pending scheduled tasks, it will pick a free thread from thread pool and use it to run the pending scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Get a look at the source code of ThreadPoolExecutor.execute() method.

Method1:To Check the ThreadPool size and pool running state.

```
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (poolSize >= corePoolSize || !addIfUnderCorePoolSize(command)) {
        if (runState == RUNNING && workQueue.offer(command)) {
            if (runState != RUNNING || poolSize == 0)
                ensureQueuedTaskHandled(command);
        }
        else if (!addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(command))
            reject(command); // is shutdown or saturated
    }
}
```

Method2:

```
    private void ensureQueuedTaskHandled(Runnable command) {
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    boolean reject = false;
    Thread t = null;
    try {
        int state = runState;
        if (state != RUNNING && workQueue.remove(command))
            reject = true;
        else if (state < STOP &&
                 poolSize < Math.max(corePoolSize, 1) &&
                 !workQueue.isEmpty())
            t = addThread(null);
    } finally {
        mainLock.unlock();
    }
    if (reject)
        reject(command);
    else if (t != null)
        t.start();
}
```

Method3:To create and start a thread using runnalbe.run() method.

```
 private Thread addThread(Runnable firstTask) {
    Worker w = new Worker(firstTask);
    Thread t = threadFactory.newThread(w);
    if (t != null) {
        w.thread = t;
        workers.add(w);
        int nt = ++poolSize;
        if (nt > largestPoolSize)
            largestPoolSize = nt;
    }
    return t;
}
```